# Problem securing Dask connections with TLS

Tags: python, ssl, dask, tls1.2, dask-distributed

I am trying to secure a dask distributed system using TLS but the scheduler throws "TypeError: TLS expects a 'ssl_context' argument of type ssl.SSLContext (perhaps check your TLS configuration?) Instead got None" when I run dask-ssh over some local to the network machines.

This is for a dask distributed system that is created using dask-ssh to initialize it. All of the computers in the hostfile.txt are local to the network and file server. I use the same 2 files created with the openssl tool for all machines. Using default TCP there are no issues. I think I am either making the TLS certificates incorrectly, or assigning them in the Dask config incorrectly. I have done a fair amount of googling of this error and I have no idea what could be the issue

Here is how I am generating the certificates:
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out /MyFakeDirectory/certs/myca.pem -keyout /MyFakeDirectory/private/mykey.pem

Leaving every asked question after that blank. 
Here are all the relevant assignments I have inside of my dask config located at: .config/dask/distributed:

```
default-scheme: tls
.
.
.
require-encryption: True
tls:
  ca-file: /MyFakeDirectory/Certs/certs/myca.pem
  scheduler:
    key: /MyFakeDirectory/Certs/private/mykey.pem
    cert: /MyFakeDirectory/Certs/certs/myca.pem
  worker:
    key: /MyFakeDirectory/Certs/private/mykey.pem
    cert: /MyFakeDirectory/Certs/certs/myca.pem
  client:
    key: /MyFakeDirectory/Certs/private/mykey.pem
    cert: /MyFakeDirectory/Certs/certs/myca.pem
  ciphers:
    ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

Comment: It may be the formatting, but if your config does actually have that indentation, then you need to indent everything below `tls:` a level. If that doesn't fix it, it's likely that `dask-ssh` isn't setup properly for working with TLS (TLS security does work for other deployment methods) - in this case please file an issue.

Comment: @jiminy_crist The formatting was lost when I copy-pasted (fixed in question); I don't believe that is the problem. I am pretty new to Dask, what other deployment methods would you recommend, because I agree that it is likely Dask-SSH. Can I automate it through script? Thank you for your response and time!

Comment: That depends on what cluster system you normally use (kubernetes, hadoop/yarn, job queue systems, etc...) - see our documentation for information about the available options: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup.html.

Comment: @jiminy_crist, Thank you for your response, I have filed an issue: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5079